# iOS 9.3.6 filling device

Tags: ios

I have an iPhone 4s running iOS 9.3.6 that regularly runs out of space. Someone in the internet (I can't find the link now) mentioned that this could be related to Location Services. Indeed, resetting Location & Privacy restores the free space to 4.1 Gb. I've been doing this regularly.

I use the iPhone mostly as remote control for my Apple TV, using iTunes Remote and Apple TV Remote, both Apple apps from the App Store. These are the only non-standard apps in the iPhone. I've reset and wiped the iPhone several times but the issue remains.

I also have two other devices running iOS 9.3.5 (an iPad mini 1 and an iPad 3), but I don't see this issue on them.

How can I fix this issue on the iPhone?

Comment: Can‘t you turn of location services (sorry for asking, don’t have an iOS 9 device to check it)?

Comment: @nohillside, that’s what I ended up doing. Too bad.